# MapKit View not zooming in to users location

Tags: ios, swift

In my application I have a `MKMapKit` view and when my application starts, if the user allows location services, I want the Map to zoom into the user's location. The code I wrote is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    mapKitView.delegate = self
    mapKitView.showsUserLocation = true
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.delegate = self

    if (CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()) {

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    let noLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2D()
    let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(noLocation, 200, 200)
    mapKitView.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: false)
}
```

In my app, it shows the users location, but does not animate and zoom in.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45250752/swift-zoom-in-on-location/45251220#45251220 maybe can help you

Answer (score 0):

Use the user's location to calculate the view region and change the `animated` parameter to `true`:

```
if let location = mapKitView.userLocation.location {
    let viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 200, 200)
    mapKitView.setRegion(viewRegion, animated: true)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In Swift 3.0** you should use this code if you want to zoom map Kit on the starting view of the map view.

```
var zoomIn = false
var zoomAnnotation:MKAnnotation

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
    if let annotation = zoomAnnotation where zoomIn == true {
           let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: zoomAnnotation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.075, longitudeDelta: 0.075))
           mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
           zoomIn = false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3.0, try my code in your didUpdateLocation method.

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])
    {
        //get location cordinate
        let locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location!.coordinate
        print(locValue)
        //set updating location stop
        locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        let location = locations.last! as CLLocation//create object of CLLocation
        //get location cordinate

        let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)

        //set map zooming using region
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
        self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

I hope it's work @Rahul Bir